# Is searching a post with latex or MathJax possible?

Tags: support, mathjax, search

The title of a post contains latex  in Title with the help of which I wish to search for it. How is

possible ?  There was no luck with e.g., $y''y^3=1$ .

Comment: You can try a google search with `y'' y^3 = 1` and `site:math.stackexchange.com`. The site's current search engine isn't too good with $\LaTeX$, unfortunately.

Comment: ... which brings http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144821/find-general-solution-yy3-1 as the second search result (for me).

Comment: Thanks,  Daniel Fischer and Famous Blue Raincoat.

Comment: BTW you will find several older posts on meta tagged [search+mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search+mathjax)